# How to count occurrences of an element in a Swift array of objects with different conditions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, find-occurrences

I am doing a test on the content of an element's attribute in order calculate occurrences

for a simple array of strings for example this example works just fine when I want to test with one condition:

```
    counts[item.id] = (counts[item.id] ?? 0) + 1
```

however my question is, how to do the same test with different conditions, by not only testing the item.id, I would like to test also with item.email for example. is it something like this

```
 counts[item.id] = (counts[item.id]  && counts[item.email] = (counts[item.email] ?? 0) + 1
```

this is the array in which I am adding key values, key as elements of my object, and values as number of occurrences

here is a clear example

```
    let arr = [Student, Student, Student, Student]
    var counts: [String: Int] = [:]

    for item in arr {
    counts[item.id] = (counts[item.id] ?? 0) + 1
    }


for (key, value) in counts {
    print("\(key) occurs \(value) time(s)")
}
output:

44442 occurs 1 time(s)
34434 occurs 1 time(s)
22222 occurs 2 time(s)
```

thank you for you help.

Comment: That looks like an array of Int to me. Please clarify your question, what are you testing here? Please add more code to make the context clear.

Comment: thanks for answering, i modified the code

Comment: Oh, it was a dictionary. That makes more sense :) So you want to check the combination of username and objectId in an `item` but still count them separately rather than counting the combination?

Comment: that is exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: Still not clear to me, say you have username A:1 and objectId 1:1 in dictionary `counts` and next `item` contains username A and objectId 2, is that a failed test so nothing is changed or should it be A:2  and for objectId 1:1 and 2:1?

Comment: i have simplified the question, can you please take a look now Joakim ?

Comment: Would it work for you ?
let dictionary = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: { $0.id })

Comment: i need for the comparaison to be done using two attributes, id and email both

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want, I thought I understood it it but apparently not. Give an example using both id and email and what your expected output is from that example.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience about how to describe the issue, see the example above ? the array of students ? let arr = [Student, Student, Student, Student]
it is basically for me an array of notifications, and the issue is for example when a user comments an activity of another user, the notification will be for example : user 1 commented activity football, my problem is to group those same notifications within one UICell when the same user comments the same activity many times, in that case i will have the same cell in the tableview duplicated, so i have to groupe them by comparing attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was very simple it was in the extension of my class and by adding the Equatable,

```
extension notificationManager: Equatable {

    static func ==(lhs: notificationManager, rhs: notificationManager) -> Bool {
    return lhs.fromwho.username == rhs.fromwho.username && lhs.forwho.username == rhs.forwho.username && lhs.activity.objectId == rhs.activity.objectId
}}
```

and then i just add the count

```
     for item in orignalNotifs {
            notificationManager.Notifcounts[item] = (notificationManager.Notifcounts[item]  ?? 0) + 1
        }
```